# Unable to connect to LDAP server - backend logging in issues (Joomla)

Tags: authentication, ldap, joomla2.5, backend

I've been unable to login to my site for weeks and weeks now. I've tried everything I can find on forums and still no joy (eg: viewtopic.php?t=719540).

A few weeks back my Joomla site backend became unavailable with the error message "Unable to connect to LDAP server".

I have not updated or changed the site in quite a while. It just started happening. So I've ruled out anything I have done.

I will say the exact steps I have taken:

1. In phpMyAdmin, accessed 'jos_extensions' and then 'plg_authentication_ldap'. Changed 'enable' from '1' to '0'.
2. Accessed 'jos_extensions' and 'plg_authentication_joomla' and ensured it was enabled. ie '1'.
3. Accessed 'jos_users' and found out I'd been hacked with many new users (with names like 'habxnkxl') had been added. All passwords were changed to things like 'jnsnbjhbx'. I removed all the unwanted users and changed all passwords for users.
4. Followed the steps in 'how to recover your password page' (http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F) and created a new super user 'admin2'.

### edit

1. Now, 'repaired' jos_extensions, jos_users and deleted plg_authentication_ldap.

I've consistently been re-checking the login throughout the process, on firefox and safari, and still get the same "Unable to connect to LDAP server" error message. Even when I have turned off 'plg_authentication_ldap".

Your help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nicol

Joomla 2.5

Comment: If anyone can help me I'd really really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set :

Client id  1
Enabled    1
Access     1

This worked for me :)

Comment: Do you mean set username ID to 1 in jos_users? Or where did you set this?